# saving uploaded files on disk, ubuntu path

Tags: java, ubuntu, path

I'm having some trouble with saving a pic on the disk from my web server. It might be something about sufficient privileges to save a file on disk. At least I think that's what the error is about. I just switched to ubuntu so I'm a bit unfamiliar with how that works.

On windows I had :

```
    System.out.println("1");
    Path folder = Paths.get("/var/webapp/images"); // not null
    System.out.println("2");

    UploadedFile uploadedFile = e.getFile();
    String filename = "profile_pic";
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadedFile
            .getFileName());
    System.out.println("3");

    Path file = Files.createTempFile(folder, filename + "-", "."
            + extension);
    System.out.println("4");
    //1,2,3,error
```

This gives me a `NoSuchFileException` on ubuntu. It's supposed to create a new file so sure there is no such file. Or maybe it means the parent? But it's not null. Or maybe it's that privilege thing ? I don't understand.

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/webapp/images/profile_pic-6949678835586050878.png
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
    at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:138)
    at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(TempFileHelper.java:161)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:852)
    at main.java.managedbeans.UserProfileEdit.fileUploadListener(UserProfileEdit.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 42 more


    System.out.println("folder path : " + folder.toAbsolutePath().toString());
```

output : `folder path : /var/webapp/images`

I did try to see if that was a privilege thing but I'm not sure what I doing really.

```
ps aux | egrep '(wildfly)'
cedric   24184  3.5 14.2 4290528 870928 ?      Sl   20:04   3:03 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: WildFly  9.x  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/home/cedric/Applications/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/home/cedric/Applications/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.home.dir=/home/cedric/Applications/wildfly-9.0.2.Final -Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/cedric/Applications/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/jboss-modules.jar org.jboss.modules.Main -mp /home/cedric/Applications/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/cedric/Applications/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone
cedric   26485  0.0  0.0  13952  2468 pts/1    S+   21:30   0:00 grep -E --color=auto (wildfly)
```

Comment: `Paths.get(...)` will never return a null path. What happens is that maybe `/var/webapp/images` does not exist. Try and `Files.createDirectories(folder)`.

Comment: @fge indeed the folder wasn't the right one. Something I don't understand though is that on windows that path was like the root was considered to be the folder where the wildfly folder is. Now on ubuntu its the real root folder /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions on `/var/webapp/images` to give cedric permission to write. The easiest way is probably to `ls -l /var/webapp | grep images` and get the group that owns `images` (and make sure `images` is group writable). Then add `cedric` to that group. Assuming it's `www-data` that might look something like

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data cedric
```

The next easiest option would be to enable and add [ACLs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs).

Comment: Thanks, it was actually because when I was on windows the root of the path was considered to be where the web app server was located. Now the root is the real / root of the ubuntu filesystem. Idk.